# How many ring homomorphisms they are:$\mathbb Z[x,\frac1x\ ] \to \mathbb Z_4,\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2) \to \mathbb Z_{24},\mathbb Z[x]/(x^3-1) \to \mathbb C$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ring-homomorphism

> How many ring homomorphisms they are? 
>   
> a) $\mathbb Z[x, \frac1x\ ] \to \mathbb Z_4$ 
>   
> b) $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^2) \to \mathbb Z_{24}$
>   
> c) $\mathbb Z[x]/(x^3-1) \to \mathbb C$

**My try:**

a) ? 
b) Assume that exist homomorphism  $\psi$.
 $\mathbb Z[x] \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb Z [x]/(x^2) \xrightarrow{\psi} \mathbb Z_{24}$ transforms $x$ on such $y\in \mathbb Z_{24}$ that: $$x^2=0 \Rightarrow x=24k, k\in \left\{0,1,...\right\}$$
c) Assume that exist homomorphism  $\psi$.
 $\mathbb Z[x] \xrightarrow{\pi} \mathbb Z [x]/(x^3-1) \xrightarrow{\psi} \mathbb C$ transforms $x$ on such $y\in \mathbb C$ that: $$x^3-1=0 \Rightarrow x=1$$

However, I don't know what to do next

Comment: You mean that $y^2=0$ and $y^3-1=0$ in each case. Note that $y^3-1=0$ does not imply that $y=-1$ at all, since $-1$ is not a cubic root of unity.

Comment: Are you writing "Abstract Algebra in Exercises" (looking for a full-time consultant)?

Comment: $x^2 \equiv 0 \bmod 24 \iff x \equiv 0 \bmod 12$

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that ring homomorphisms send $1$ to $1$, it is enough to determine the possible images of $x$ or its class.

a) We need to send $x$ to a unit of $\mathbb Z_4$. The only possibilities are $1,3$.

b) We need to send $x$ to an element $y$ of $\mathbb Z_{24}$ such that $y^2=0$. The only possibilities are $0,12$.

b) We need to send $x$ to an element $z$ of $\mathbb C$ such that $z^3=1$. There are three possibilities.